# How to disable sitcky screen edges in Ubuntu 18 Gnome?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, mouse

I can't move mouse from monitor to monitor easily: it sticks at edges causes some special effects (including radiance animation, window switcher turning on and so on).

How to get rid of this "feature"?

[image]

It's not `edge-tilling`, which is already turned off

[image]

Comment: `dcon-editor` tool or `gsettings` cli should have option to control this. didn't you try those??

Comment: what's the name of parameter?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I tried just now and did not find anything.. can you share a pic like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYQpM.png

Comment: @PRATAP you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can do command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides edge-tiling false
```

needs reboot after